# Custom sorting of XML elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Given input XML of the following form:

```
<root>
    <alpha />
    <beta />
    <gamma />
</root>
```

I'd like to be able to process the elements in a custom order, defined in an XSL stylesheet. I've tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="http://tempurl.org" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="my">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <!-- Elements should be processed in the following order: -->
    <my:sorting>
        <my:item id="beta" />
        <my:item id="gamma" />
        <my:item id="alpha" />
    </my:sorting>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:variable name="sortOrder" select="document('')/*/my:sorting/my:item" />

        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="count($sortOrder[@id=name()]/preceding-sibling::*)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but this has no effect on the ordering.

Is a solution along these lines possible? Have I just made some simple error in the XSL?

(I am aware of a different solution involving `string-length` and `substring-before`, but I'd like to know how to get things working in a similar fashion to that above, if possible.)

Comment: <xsl:template match="..." priority="..."> could help

Comment: Do you mean to have a separate template for each element I'd like to match, and give each template a priority? I'd like to use the same template each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the `xsl:sort`

```
<xsl:sort select="count($sortOrder[@id=name()]/preceding-sibling::*)"/>
```

In the expression, `name()` is context sensitive. It is part of a condition applying to a node set (`sortOrder`)  and so will return the name of the `sortOrder` element. Essentially, it is looking for `sortOrder` elements whose name equal their `id` attribute.

To get around this, use the `current()` function

```
<xsl:sort select="count($sortOrder[@id=name(current())]/preceding-sibling::*)"/>
```

An alternate approach, although not as elegant, is to define the sort order as a delimited string, like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="sortOrder" select="'|beta|alpha|gamma|'" />
```

Then your sort expression becomes this, to essential sort by the position of the element name in the string.

```
 <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($sortOrder, concat('|', name(), '|')))" data-type="number"/>
```

In this case, `name()` is not part of an condition, so the context is the elements you are sorting.

Comment: Sorry Tim, I thought this would work but I just tried it out at http://www.xmlplayground.com/nQ4nT0 and it doesn't seem to. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's most likely because on-line XSLT testers disallow the use of the "document" function for security reasons. Try testing it locally, perhaps by simply adding the stylesheet directive to your XML `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>`